# How To Resolve Duplicate When Joining 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a duplicate error in my database, when I enter 2 records then I want to display them through the terminal using the SELECT command and join between the two tables, they display 4 records. here I use 2 automatic codes for no_servis and kode_pelanggan
the previous one was fine, when I changed one of the columns in the database then returned it to the original. instead an error like this

```
MariaDB [sijarvis]> SELECT * FROM tb_penerimaan;
| no_servis   | tgl_terima | kode_pelanggan | nama_perangkat | model_perangkat | no_model | keluhan       | kelengkapan    | dp    | status    | solusi        | harga  | presentase |

| SER00000001 | 2019-01-25 | PE000001       | ASUS           | Elitebook 8460p | CVT123   | projek        | meh            |  5000 | Di Servis | Instal Office | 150000 | 15         |
| SER00000002 | 2019-01-28 | PE000002       | ASUS           | X453SA          | asdasd   | nsdklfnskslii | nflsfndklnskln | 10012 | Di Servis |               |      0 |            |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sijarvis]> SELECT * FROM tb_pelanggan;
+----------------+-------+--------+-------------+--------+
| kode_pelanggan | nama  | alamat | no_hp       | member |
+----------------+-------+--------+-------------+--------+
| PE000001       | admin | Hatimu | 05628675848 | member |
| PE000002       | Anggi | balen  | 987304209   | member |
+----------------+-------+--------+-------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sijarvis]> SELECT tb_penerimaan.* , tb_pelanggan.nama FROM tb_penerimaan, tb_pelanggan;
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+-------+
| no_servis   | tgl_terima | kode_pelanggan | nama_perangkat | model_perangkat | no_model | keluhan       | kelengkapan    | dp    | status    | solusi        | harga  | presentase | nama  |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+-------+
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-25 | PE000001       | ASUS           | Elitebook 8460p | CVT123   | projek        | meh            |  5000 | Di Servis | Instal Office | 150000 | 15         | admin |
| SER00000002 | 2019-01-28 | PE000002       | ASUS           | X453SA          | asdasd   | nsdklfnskslii | nflsfndklnskln | 10012 | Di Servis |               |      0 |            | admin |
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-25 | PE000001       | ASUS           | Elitebook 8460p | CVT123   | projek        | meh            |  5000 | Di Servis | Instal Office | 150000 | 15         | Anggi |
| SER00000002 | 2019-01-28 | PE000002       | ASUS           | X453SA          | asdasd   | nsdklfnskslii | nflsfndklnskln | 10012 | Di Servis |               |      0 |            | Anggi |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

why when i joined two tables showed up 4 record?
this is my query insert from tambah_transaksi.php

```
    <?php
  include('koneksi.php');
// Proses input data 
  $no_servis  = $_POST['no_servis'];
  $tgl_terima = $_POST['tgl_terima'];
  $nama_perangkat   = $_POST['nama_perangkat'];
  $model_perangkat  = $_POST['model_perangkat'];
  $no_model  = $_POST['no_model'];
  $keluhan = $_POST['keluhan'];
  $kelengkapan = $_POST['kelengkapan'];
  $dp = $_POST['dp'];
  $kode_pelanggan = $_POST['kode_pelanggan'];
  $nama = $_POST['nama'];
  $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
  $nohp = $_POST['no_hp'];
  $member = $_POST['member'];
  $hak_akses = $_POST['hak_akses'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $solusi = $_POST['solusi'];
  $presentase = $_POST['presentase'];
  $harga  = $_POST['harga'];

// query SQL untuk insert data

  $query1 = "INSERT INTO tb_penerimaan VALUES('$no_servis','$tgl_terima','$kode_pelanggan','$nama_perangkat','$model_perangkat','$no_model','$keluhan','$kelengkapan','$dp','$status','$solusi','$harga','$presentase')";
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO tb_pelanggan VALUES('$kode_pelanggan','$nama','$alamat','$nohp','$member')";
  $query3 = "INSERT INTO login VALUES('$kode_pelanggan','$nama','$password','$hak_akses')";

  $hasil = mysql_query($query1);
  $hasil = mysql_query($query2);
  $hasil = mysql_query($query3);

    header("location: nota-masuk.php?no_servis='$no_servis'");

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** The `mysql_*`-functions was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and totally removed in PHP 7.0. Use MySQLI or PDO instead. Also, you are _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks since you're using unescaped user data directly in your queries. You should use parameterized prepared statements instead (which you can use with MySQLi and PDO).

Comment: Right now, you are not even using explicit JOINs, but are just producing the _cross product_, so these duplicates are to be expected. Go read up on what the different _types_ of JOINs are, and figure out which one might be appropriate to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  join

```
SELECT tb_penerimaan.* , tb_pelanggan.nama 
FROM tb_penerimaan 
INNER JOIN  tb_pelanggan ON tb_penerimaan.tb_penerimaan  = tb_pelanggan.kode_pelanggan ;
```

If don't add the condition for join you obtain a cartesian product fo the rows (for each rows in one table you select all the rows of the other)  .. whit join you buil the relation that select only the matching rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tb_penerimaan.* , tb_pelanggan.nama FROM tb_penerimaan inner join
 tb_pelanggan ON tb_pelanggan.kode_pelanggan=tb_penerimaan.kode_pelanggan;

in this two table, this is common id (kode_pelanggan) so when we join the to
table use ON condition to match this then you get a unique id you don't get
duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

but when i updated "SER00000001" in tb_penerimaan, there was an error `Duplicate entry 'SER00000001' for key 'PRIMARY'` and in the table tb_penerimaan there are only two record

```
SELECT * FROM tb_penerimaan;
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
| no_servis   | tgl_terima | kode_pelanggan | nama_perangkat | model_perangkat | no_model | keluhan       | kelengkapan    | dp    | status    | solusi        | harga  | presentase |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-25 | PE000001       | ASUS           | Elitebook 8460p | CVT123   | projek        | meh            |  5000 | Di Servis | Instal Office | 150000 | 15         |
| SER00000002 | 2019-01-28 | PE000002       | ASUS           | X453SA          | asdasd   | nsdklfnskslii | nflsfndklnskln | 10012 | Di Servis |
          |      0 |            |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
```